# Can't connect to my OpenSuse machine

Tags: ssh, login, opensuse

I have a OpenSuse based machine used as my application server in client's place. I configured it and installed all necessary software in the end of December 2019 (about 1 month ago) and everything worked perfectly. Until today. I login by ssh, inserted login and password and nothing happened for the next 50 seconds. Then it logged me in successfully, and I was able to partially "work". Partially, because most of the system features won't work.

For example, when I type `mc` in console, it just "freezes". I waited about 5 minutes and nothing happened. Then I reconnected to server. I tried to restart server by `sudo reboot now`. It disconnected me from ssh, but in next 10 minutes I wasn't able to connect to server again. I had my other server in this location, so I logged to this server and tried to ping to my "laggy" server. And it was successful, but when I tried to ssh into it's "connection refused". I asked someone from the factory who was at the time near the server to restart it manually. It worked for a while because I can connect to server after this, but it's still laggy. I disconnected and tried to connect once more but now I can't connect to it. Server asks me for credentials:

```
login as: root
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
Password:
```

when I insert CORRECT password, nothing happens for about 30-40 seconds and then this text shows up:

```
Last login: Tue Jan 21 13:14:38 2020 from 192.168.0.1
Have a lot of fun...
```

And that's all. I've waited about 20mins on this and nothing else happened. It worked perfectly from end of December till yesterday. I can't even add any logs or something because I can't connect to this server.

Server spec:
i5 9600k
24gigs of RAM ddr4
3x HDD 1TB (they are all in RAID1)

It runs only postgres database, some samba shares, apache2 and nodejs server.

Comment: Is there some sort of automount active for your user that tries to mount a home directory? Is `sssd` service running?

Comment: No, there are no any automounts. If you mean sshd, yes its running.

Comment: No, I mean sssd

Comment: Ouch, I don't really know because I can't reach this server. It is possible that server behave like that because of sssd service not running?

Comment: We have faced similar issues in the past with LDAP and sssd, it could be a laggy mount, there are several things to check. If you get to the stage where you see `Have a lot of fun...` press `CTRL + C`, that should give you a bash prompt from where you can analyze further.

Comment: After `Have a lot of fun...` I can't do anything. I grab the computer and take it to our office. I've run it locally and it "freezes" too. I run `tail -f /var/log/messages` and I saw that the last thing to show before complete freeze is something with opensuse.snapper. I planned to reinstall system on this pc anyway so I took a chance to fix it by deleting snapper services by Package Manager. And for now (about 30 mins) it looks like it works. I will give further info after few more tests, but for now I think it worked.

Comment: Is it installed with btrfs filesystem? It could be out of space because of too many snapshots.